# How to create/close the server when running integration tests using Express and Supertest in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, supertest

My problem is I am always getting the "`Address already in use::3000`" error when running my tests.

Here is what I have:

*package.json*

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --watchAll --verbose --runInBand --maxWorkers=1"
 },
```

*server.js*

```
const winston = require('winston');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

module.exports = function() {
    const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

    return app.listen(port, () => { winston.info(`Listening on port ${port}...`) });
}
```

*auth.test.js (showing only one test)*

```
describe('auth middleware', () => {
    beforeEach(() => { server = require('../../startup/server'); });
    afterEach(async () => { 
        await Category.remove({});
        await server.close(); 
    });

    let token;

    const exec = () => {
        return request(server)
            .post('/api/categories')
            .set('x-auth-token', token)
            .send({ name: 'category1' });
    }

    beforeEach(() => {
        token = new User().generateAuthToken();
    });

    it('should return 200 if token is valid', async () => {
        const res = await exec();

        expect(res.status).toBe(200);
    });
});
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, most of the answers on stackoverflow point to add `runInBand` or `maxWorkers=1` to `package.json` or await the `server.close()`.  Nothing works for me.

PS: I had this issue before with one test, but after extracting the server logic to separate file (from `index.js`), now all tests fail with this error, so clearly I am missing something.
And I am not running the app, just my tests.

Comment: You don't need to bind a port to use supertest; just expose the app object, move it out of the server file.

Comment: Can you give me more details ? You mean I don't need the server ? I am actually testing with a testing database. So not sure I know what you mean

Comment: I mean you don't need the app to listen to a specific port for the tests to work. Look at the [examples](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest#example), *"it is bound to an ephemeral port for you"*.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks, you can add this as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an minimal working example:

`server.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/api/categories', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

if (require.main === module) {
  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.info(`Listening on port ${port}...`);
  });
}

module.exports = app;
```

`auth.test.js`:

```js
const request = require('supertest');
const server = require('./server');

describe('auth middleware', () => {
  const exec = () => {
    return request(server)
      .post('/api/categories')
      .set('x-auth-token', 'token')
      .send({ name: 'category1' });
  };
  it('should return 200 if token is valid', async () => {
    const res = await exec();
    expect(res.status).toBe(200);
  });
});
```

Integration test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/58569731/auth.test.js (8.919s)
  auth middleware
    ✓ should return 200 if token is valid (70ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/58569731/server.js:8
    { name: 'category1' }

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.993s, estimated 10s
```

Start the HTTP web server:

```js
 node /Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/58569731/server.js       
Listening on port 3000...
```

`npm scripts`:

```
"test": "jest --detectOpenHandles --verbose",
```

Source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/58569731